# Nuxtで開発中のアプリでpdfmakeライブラリをインストール後、./node_modules/pdfmakeディレクトリでnpm run buildが実行できないです。

Tags: node.js, npm, nuxt.js, pdf

**開発環境**

- Nuxt.js (Vue)
- firebase/firestore/cloudfunctions
- 質問対象ライブラリ[pdfmake]

#### 問題点

インストールしたライブラリ[pdfmake]のディレクトリ配下で、

```
npm install
npm run build
```

を実行したいのですが、`npm run build` 実行時に以下のエラーが出てしまいます。

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src' in '/Users/***
```

pdfmakeで出力するPDFを日本語化対応するために、どうしてもbuildしなおす必要があるのですが、原因・対処法がわかる方いましたら、ご教示いただけますと助かります。

#### 質問内容の詳細

Nuxt.jsで開発中のアプリで、データをPDF出力する機能をもたせています。
その際、pdfmakeライブラリというものを利用しているのですが、日本語の全角数字・記号も表示できるフォントを読み込む必要があり、色々とやり方を調べていたところ、以下の記事等が見つかりました。

[pdfmakeでカスタムフォントを使用したPDFファイル生成](https://qiita.com/watame/items/5f82abead68db483d6f2)

こちらの方法で、目的の日本語フォントを適用することができたのですが、
実際にプロジェクトにpdfmakeをインストールし、日本語フォントを適用しようとすると、
pdfmakeライブラリの再ビルド時にエラーとなってしまいます。

こちらはプロジェクトにpdfmakeをインストールする際に参考にした記事です。

[pdfmakeで日本語フォントを適用する](https://ls.urnia.xyz/frontend/js-pdfmake-change-font.html)

githubからクローンしたpdfmakeは `npm run build` が正常にできたにも関わらず、プロジェクトで `npm install pdfmake` のコマンドでインストールしたpdfmakeライブラリでは `npm run build` がエラーになるのかわかりません。

なにかわかる方、いましたらアドバイスいただけますと助かります。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

こちら、結局

```
npm run build
```

を実行することはできなかったのですが、

[PDFMAKE公式マニュアル](http://pdfmake.github.io/docs/0.1/fonts/custom-fonts-client-side/vfs)を参考にして、vfs_fonts.jsを新たに作成し、 それを任意のディレクトリに配置し、IMPORTすることで新しいフォントを利用することができるようになりました。